# How to deal with multiple callbacks with Moq unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, callback, moq

I have a mocked executor that Asserts the unit after x amount of callbacks depending on what values we give to the parameters. Here's a sample code of my unit test

```
[Test]
[TestCase("foo", false, 2)]
[TestCase("foo", true, 3)]
public void CommandLineShouldBeValidTest(string parameter1, bool parameter2, int finalCallbackCounter)
{
    int initialCallbackCounter = 0;

    var executorMock = new Mock<ITaskExecutor>();
    executorMock.Setup(m => m.Execute(It.IsAny<IExecutionContext>(), It.IsAny<ITask>()))
                .Callback<IExecutionContext, ITask>((c, it) =>
    {
        var p = (ProcessTask)it;
        initialCallbackCounter++;

        if (initialCallbackCounter == finalCallbackCounter)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedCommandLine, p.CommandLine);
        }
    });

    var macro = new Macro(parameter1, parameter2, executorMock.Object);
    macro.Execute();
}
```

For the moment I'm using the `finalCallbackCounter` parameter for it, so for example if I make the second boolean parameter true instead of false, I need to change it to 3 (I actually have more arguments and cases in my current code, I just simplified it for the question's purpose).

This way to do it feels really finnicky and not very futureproof. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `SetupSequence` instead of `Setup`?

Comment: Looking at the example here I don't see how it would be helpful? https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous unless there is a way to rewrite my test using Returns() that I don't know of

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly do you use the mock (`executorMock`)? I can not spot where do pass the `executorMock.Object` to the SUT.

Comment: @PeterCsala edited the code to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the `ITask`s, then assert at the end.

`Setup` is not intended for assertions:

```
var capturedTasks = new List<ITask>();

var executorMock = new Mock<ITaskExecutor>();
executorMock.Setup(m => m.Execute(
    It.IsAny<IExecutionContext>(),
    Capture.In(capturedTasks)));

var macro = new Macro(mock.Object);
macro.Execute();

if (capturedTasks.Count >= finalCallbackCounter)
{
    var p = (ProcessTask)capturedTasks[finalCallbackCounter - 1];
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCommandLine, p.CommandLine);
}
```

Comment: This is good, thank you, although my goal is to get rid of the finalCallbackCounter so that I don't have to add it as a parameter and manually modify it for each testcase

Comment: So you just want the final invocation? i.e. `Assert.AreEqual(expectedCommandLine, capturedTasks.Cast<ProcessTask>().Last().CommandLine);`?

Comment: Also not necessarily, sometimes the task will be called 5+ times while I need to assert the second call.

Comment: In that case you need to specify the invocation count. Unless it can be inferred somehow?